# Stuck on Instruction SVC0 __asm void prvStartFirstTask( void ){...}; in STM32F4

Tags: arm, microcontroller, stm32, freertos, stm32f4discovery

In my project,

> boot loader Flash address: 0x08000000
>
> application Flash address: 0x08004000
>
> Same RAM for boot and app: 0x20000000(IRAM1) and 0x10000000(IRAM2)

1. Separately boot Loader and Application(With or Without FreeRTOS) working fine.
2. Boot Loader and application(Without FreeRTOS) working perfectly.
3. But if i use freeRTOS in my application with two task (Display and communication) :

   jump  boot loader -> application

   application running -> Initialize all peripherals(GPIO,Display, Eth, GSM,SPI etc)

   Create Task1 -> without any Error

   Create Task2 -> Without any Error

   ```
   task1=osCreateTask("Task Display_Data", Task_Display_Data, NULL, 512, 3);//brick    
        if(task1 == OS_INVALID_HANDLE)
        {
               //Debug message
               TRACE_ERROR("Failed to create task!\r\n");
        } 

   task2=osCreateTask("Communication_Task",Communication_Task, NULL, 512, 1);
            if(task2 == OS_INVALID_HANDLE)
            {  
                   //Debug message
                   TRACE_ERROR("Failed to create task!\r\n");
            }

          vTaskStartScheduler();
          while(1);
   ```

   vTaskStartScheduler -> xPortStartScheduler ->prvStartFirstTask() ->

   ```
       __asm void prvStartFirstTask( void )
      {
        PRESERVE8

        /* Use the NVIC offset register to locate the stack. */
        ldr r0, =0xE000ED08
        ldr r0, [r0]
        ldr r0, [r0]
       /* Set the msp back to the start of the stack. */
        msr msp, r0
      /* Globally enable interrupts. */
       cpsie i
       cpsie f
       dsb
       isb
       /* Call SVC to start the first task. */
   ```

> ```
>        svc 0    //it's stuck on this line
> ```

```
       nop
       nop
      }
```

This is my jump code (boot to app)

```
   void INTFLASH_execute_main_app()
          {
             pFunction Jump_To_Application;
             uint32_t  JumpAddress;

             JumpAddress         = *(__IO uint32_t*) (IAP_APP_ADDRESS + 4);
             Jump_To_Application =  ( pFunction) JumpAddress;   
             RCC_APB2PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
             RCC_APB2PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, DISABLE);
             GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB); 
             SPI_DeInit(SPI2);
             RCC_DeInit();

   __disable_irq();

   __DSB();
   __ISB(); 

   SYSCFG->MEMRMP = 0x01;
   SCB->VTOR = IAP_APP_ADDRESS;
   __set_MSP( *(__IO uint32_t*)IAP_APP_ADDRESS );  // Initialise app's Stack Pointer
    __DSB(); 

 SysTick->CTRL &= 0xFFFFFFFE;
 SysTick->LOAD = 0;
 SysTick->VAL = 0;

 Jump_To_Application();
 }
```

Comment: My guess is your heap is too small or not actually implemented.

Comment: @Russ Schultz I already increased both task heap size 256 byte to 512 byte . But it's not working. And another thing is that if I separately run this code it's working fine

Comment: you increased their STACK size.   Where is that stack coming from?  I don't see you allocating it anywhere, so it must be coming from the OS HEAP.

Comment: @Russ I am using FreeRTOS so, in my code i am using heap_3.c. don't confuse with (custom task)function name.

Comment: And  i already mention in my question if i separately run my application code no error found, it's working fine. I think ,vect table in ram not configure properly

Comment: Yes i solved it,There is VECT_TABLE_OFFSET problem. Thank you for your reply @RussSchultz

Comment: @MalikJi , can you provide the solution in detail